# how to toggle class for multiple elements in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to toggle classes for multiple elements in `Vuejs 2.0`, I have the following set of buttons which has a class of `btn-primary`. Clicking a button shows a sub-group of that particular element. This is my code:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" v-on:click.prevent="getTags('investor')">Investor</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" v-on:click.prevent="getTags('research')">Research</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" v-on:click.prevent="getTags('company')">Company</button>
```

This shows the following element:

```
<div v-if="tag.investor">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" v-on:click.prevent="selectTags('Investor - Mutual Funds')">Mutual Fund</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" v-on:click.prevent="selectTags('Investor - Insurance')">Insurance</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" v-on:click.prevent="selectTags('Investor - FII')">FII</button>
</div>
<div v-if="tag.research">
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" v-on:click.prevent="selectTags('Research - Tier I')">Research - Tier I</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" v-on:click.prevent="selectTags('Research - Tier II')">Research - Tier II</button>
</div>
```

I have the following in `data()`:

```
tag: {
    investor: false,
    research: false,
    company: false,
    others: false,
 },
```

And in `methods`:

```
getTags: function (tag) {
    this.tag.investor = this.tag.research = this.tag.company = this.tag.others = false
    if(tag == 'investor')
    {
        this.tag.investor = true
    }
    if(tag == 'research')
    {
        this.tag.research = true
    }
    if(tag == 'company')
    {
        this.tag.company = true
    }
    if(tag == 'others')
    {
        this.tag.others = true
    }
},
```

I want to have a class of `btn-warning` and remove `btn-primary` once any child element is being selected. Any ideas how to implement this, I don't want to have individual data elements and toggle class.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd like to suggest a data driven approach for your Vue. Consider this data structure:

```
const tags = {
   Investor:[
     {display:"Mutual Fund", value:"Investor - Mutual Funds"},
     {display:"Insurance", value:"Investor - Insurance"},
     {display:"FII", value:"Investor - FII"},
   ],
   Research:[
     {display:"Research - Tier I", value:"Research - Tier I"},
     {display:"Research - Tier II", value:"Research - Tier II"},
  ]
}
```

If you use that, then you can clean up your template considerably and handle any additional tags that you add to your data structure.

```
<div id="app">
  <button v-for="(obj, key) in tags"
          :key="key"
          @click="currentTag = key"
          class="btn btn-xs btn-primary">
    {{key}}
  </button>

  <div>  
    <button v-for="tag in tags[currentTag]"
            :key="tag"
            class="btn btn-xs"
            :class="tagClass(tag)"
            @click="selectTags(tag.value)">
      {{tag.display}}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Your Vue also looks a lot cleaner.

```
new Vue({
  el:"#app",
  data:{
    currentTag: null,
    tags,
    selectedTags:[]
  },
  methods:{
    selectTags(tag){
      const index = this.selectedTags.findIndex(t => t == tag)

      if (index >= 0)
        this.selectedTags.splice(index, 1)
      else
        this.selectedTags.push(tag)
    },
    tagClass(tag){
      const isSelected = this.selectedTags.includes(tag.value)

      return {
        'btn-warning': isSelected,
        'btn-primary': !isSelected
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Here is an [example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/qmQRqm?editors=1010).

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, it work perfect. One final doubt, what if I want to select only one end element. Just for knowledge.

Comment: @NitishKumar When you say "one end element" what do you mean? Do you mean select one tag? One tag per category?

Comment: Only one tag from any category. I mean I want the final or selectedTag to be one value not array of multiple value.

Comment: @NitishKumar Something like [this](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/vmQQKW?editors=1010).

Comment: Yes, that's perfect. Thanks for the update and helping me out. Cheers

Comment: The perfect answer ever. Never thinks of adding the method to CSS class like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `v-bind:class` directive.

```
<button 
  class="btn btn-xs" 
  v-bind:class="{ 'btn-warning': tag.research, 'btn-primary': !tag.research }"
  v-on:click.prevent="selectTags('Research - Tier I')"
>
  Research - Tier I
</button>
```

Comment: i know I an use `v-bind:class` but I'm having lot more elements which will be repetitive and very difficult to manage as all element class will be toggled then. Like suppose what will be the happen to `Research Tier II` element, or what if I've `Research Tier III, IV` element